# Struggling to convert a MongoDB singleResult object into Go struct

Tags: mongodb, go

I tried to follow documentation [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) and [here](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#SingleResult) but had no luck.

I want to get a `singleResult` from `FindOne` on the `Collection` named `moviesCollection` and then use `Decode` or `Unmarshal` to put those values into a struct. The values in the struct `JSONData` are exactly the same as in each `Document`

I am using the official mongodb driver `github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver`

**Here is an example of what I have tried:**

```
mongoContext, cancelContext := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

defer cancelContext()

mongoClient, _ := mongo.Connect(mongoContext, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
moviesCollection := mongoClient.Database("Entertainment").Collection("Movies")

moviesCollection.InsertOne(mongoContext, bson.M{"_id": "Deadpool", "Path": "path/to/file"})

singleResult := moviesCollection.FindOne(mongoContext, bson.M{"_id": "Deadpool"})

if singleResult.Err() != nil {
    log.Println("Find error: ", singleResult.Err())
}

JSONData := struct {
    Path string `json:"Path"`
}{}

decodeError := singleResult.Decode(&JSONData)

if decodeError != nil {
    log.Println("Decode error: ", decodeError)
}

fmt.Println("Path: ", JSONData.Path)
```

However no errors are produced and `JSON.Path` produces and empty string.

I have also tried using `bson.D{{"_id", "Deadpool"}}` instead of `bson.M{"_id": "Deadpool"}`

I can confirm that `JSON.Path` is not empty string as I have checked the database natively using `MongoDB Compass`. **The entry contains the following:**

```
{"_id":"Deadpool","Path":"path/to/file"}
```

Comment: You question doesn't contain sufficient detail and hence it's really hard to help you. Can you try to reproduce a smaller example that inserts the data into the DB and then tries to find it there? Or show a mongodb console dump of how the data with that `_id` looks, etc.

Comment: @EliBendersky Sorry, I will try to add more detail

Comment: @EliBendersky I have now updated it with a full reproduceable example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internally, MongoDB uses *bson*.  Change your struct as below should work.

From

```
JSONData := struct {
    Path string `json:"Path"`
}{}
```

to

```
JSONData := struct {
    Path string `bson:"Path"`
}{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey so as simagix mentioned you should be able to change your tag from JSON to bson:

```
`bson:"Path"`
```

Another option, incase you need to obtain a more generic result is to pass it a D object like so:

```
JSONData := &bson.D{}
decodeError := singleResult.Decode(JSONData)
```

You can then obtain all the information through a map using the JSON.Data.Map function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mongo-go-driver >= v.0.1.0` then, taking a look to the [go-doc](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) it looks pretty straightforward:

```
filter := bson.D{{"hello", "world"}}
err := collection.FindOne(context.Background(), filter).Decode(&result)
if err != nil { return err }
// do something with result...
```

So, what you need is:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson"
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo
)

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := mongo.NewClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    if err != nil {
       ...
    }

    if err := client.Connect(ctx); err != nil {
        ...
    }

    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    collection := client.Database("myDb").Collection("movies")

    filter := bson.D{{"_id", "sometitle"}}

    var result JSONData

    err := collection.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil { 
        ...
    }

    // Do Something cool here

}
```

I see you are using `Title` to filter the doc. Pay attention.

Comment: The only difference in this code, to my code is the use of `bson.D{{"_id", "Sometitle"}}` instead of `bson.M{"_id", "Sometitle}`. However sadly it still produces the same results.

Comment: What do you mean by `I see you are using Title to filter the doc. Pay attention.`

Comment: Hey, I meant that before the editing I've seen you were using `Title` instead of a plain string. If my solution does not work it's really weird. Check the version of the driver that you are using and make sure your `bson` tags are correct in `JSONData`.

Comment: Oh right yeah sorry, Title is a variable that is holding a string. I have the lastest version from GitHub as of about 2 days ago. How would I check the version? I have checked and bson tags are correct, this is confirmed even further as `Decode` doesn't return a noDocumentFound error, but does if I use a _id I know isn't present.